# Quick Puzzle: What is it?

Tags: computer-puzzle

What is it? Is it zebra?

0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0

Hint 1:

> Zebras are black with white stripes.

Comment: for the lazy: it's 112 characters (16 x 7)

Comment: I found this, but I can't connect the binary string to it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZEBRA_%28computer%29

Comment: It can be also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zebra_(programming_language), but I haven't found a relation yet

Comment: It can't be a zebra. It must be a unicorn.

Comment: Does it have a tail?

Comment: That is not known, all I know is zebras have stripes

Comment: I disagree. Zebras are white with black stripes.

Comment: @IanMacDonald I thought they were green with white and black stripes covering them all

Comment: @IanMacDonald off-topic, but a valid proposition. You are incorrect, embryological evidence shows that the animal's background color is black and the white stripes and bellies are additions: Prothero D.R, Schoch R. M (2003). Horns, Tusks, and Flippers: The Evolution of Hoofed Mammals. Johns Hopkins University Press. ISBN 978-0801871351.

Comment: i have the suspicion that it might be some kind of barcode. that consists of black and white stripes, as zebras, and has a straightforward conversion to binary representation

Comment: No, it's just a horse.  There aren't any zebras around here.  (for the uninitiated, old joke about panicking: hear hoofbeats and think zebra instead of horse)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, it's not a Zebra. It's a **zebra shark**.

> I was pursuing the way of the barcode already, but thanks to @elias comment, it became crystal clear that the 1 and 0 were to be composed in a barcode.

First attempt:

> I put together the 1 as black stripes and 0 as white stripes but it didn't work. http://www.onlinebarcodereader.com/ (and a bunch of other online barcode readers didn't read anything)

Second attempt:

> [image: barcode] I tried viceversa and voilà. Reading it using http://www.onlinebarcodereader.com/ we get the word (not yet meaningful) **Zebedee**. Link to the fiddle used to prepare the barcode: https://jsfiddle.net/cfk43z5v/1/

Now, with the help of Google:

> After digging into the Bible character Zebedee, a simple googling of "[zebedee zebra](https://www.google.it/search?q=zebedee%20zebra)" led me to the extraordinary zebra shark ([bbc](http://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-16420848) and [national geographic](http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2012/01/120106-virgin-birth-shark-dubai-science/)) that had a *virgin birth*. Now, I can't believe I'm on a wrong way and that this is just a coincidence. I think that's a **zebra shark**!!
>  **Edit:** as the OP pointed out below, the same google search leads to the [zebra Zebedee](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/newstopics/howaboutthat/5441692/Horse-racing-trainer-rides-zebra-to-Dorset-pub.html). So I must say that **it's also an actual zebra**!!

Comment: Well done! I left the very last googling part as a exercise to all, there are a lot of linked zebra articles (including a race-zebra with the same name)

Answer (score 7):

**No, it is not a Zebra.**

> [Decimal to Hexadecimal](http://binarytranslator.com/):
>
>  `0010110111100010011101010011011110110111100101001101111011110110010100110111101001101111000101001110011100010100`
>
>  becomes:
>
>
>  `7fffffffffffffff` (16 characters)
>
>
>  Hex-color codes are usually 6 characters (from `0 to F`), but in some programming languages (like [Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Color)) it uses two additional Hex-characters for transparency, where `FF` is 100% visible.
>
>  So:
>
>
>  `7fffff(ff)` = [Light-blue](http://www.colorhexa.com/7fffff)
>  `ffffff(ff)` = [White](http://www.colorhexa.com/ffffff);
>
>
>  And I've never seen a light-blue & white Zebra.

Comment: How did you convert that binary to that hex? Every tool I tried gave me something like `2DE27537B794DE00000000000000`

Comment: @AlessandroNiciforo Ah, you're completely right.. I just played with [this binary converter](http://binarytranslator.com/). I think I miss-clicked by accident to be honest, since I thought I selected `Binary to Hexadecimal`.. Instead, I've used `Decimal to Hexadecimal` which gave me `7fffffffffffffff`.

Comment: Your calculator hit its limit, converting original number as binary to hex gives: 2de27537b794def6537a6f14e714, converting original number as decimal to hex gives: 44e0a4d72d6cccd9fa08e7e7fc97b152121f469d4174f567b377ad158fdcd96c063926337c2b281c54a3ac41674

Comment: @JJChivers That's pretty bad.. (That's what I get for using some cheap-ass tool online instead of writing a converter myself.. :p) Ah well, I leave my answer instead of deleting it, since it was plausible.. and it might also give some hints to others regarding possible strategies.